# How to specify Restlet customer HTTP header with key as "Authorization"

Tags: restlet

I am using Restlet2.3 to run REST API test automation.

The new feature has a customer HTTP header to pass a token to the service.

```
Form headers = (Form)resource.getRequestAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
if (headers == null) {
    headers = new Form();
    resource.getRequestAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", headers);
}           

...

headers.add(key, value);
```

The code works. Now, the customer HTTP header is defined as "Authorization". The above code seems not passing the header properly. And this is not challengeScheme involved.

I tested this scenario on SoapUI and Postman. Both work.

Anyone knows that restlet support this?

Comment: ... headers.add(key, value) .. is part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can't override standard headers like `Authorization` with Restlet when doing a request.

If you want to provide a security token, you could use this approach:

```
String pAccessToken = "some token";
ChallengeResponse challengeResponse = new ChallengeResponse(
                      new ChallengeScheme("", ""));
challengeResponse.setRawValue(pAccessToken);
clientResource.setChallengeResponse(challengeResponse);
```

This way you'll have only the token in the `Authorization` header (with a space at the beginning - so don't forget to trim the value).

Comment: Thanks Thierry, I think I made progress by using the approach. The service received Authorization token as the set. I think the format is "Authorization<space><space>token and it is not the expected one. I got error at this line: slurper.parseText(resource.post(rep).getText()).  The second space is to be removed. How could I trim it out within resource?

Comment: In fact the format will be `Authorization:  token`. There will be additional space in the header value... I'm not sure to understand what `slurper.parseText(resource.post(rep).getText())` and where it takes place ;-) Feel free to give more details!

Comment: I am wondering where to remove the extra space inside resource.